# Flutter - Making Scrollable child inside a Column with List view Builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I'm building a Calculator App in which I wanted a Scrollable Child for the previous Calculations, but as I've already used Column for listing the different Widgets It's Showing me hassize kind of Error.

Below is the Image for a portion of the Design with the area selected which I want to be Scrollable

[image]

Here is the Code which I Wrote for the View ( Page )

```
SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        ThemeSwitcher(height: height),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.15, right: width * 0.03),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
// From here I want the Widget to be Scollable based on the List declared before
              Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
                        textEval[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: (width * 0.045),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          height: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
// The Elements between these two comments I want to be in a scrollable child view
              Text(
                textEval[textEval.length - 2],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: (width * 0.045),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  height: 2,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                mainText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: (width * 0.08),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  height: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Can anyone Tell me how to achieve this??

Answer (score 2):

This is a common pattern in Flutter.You might have already tried

```
Column(
    children: [
        ...,
        SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column()   // 2nd column
        )
    ]
)
```

It will not work because SingleChildScrollView can take infinite height and Column can allow infinite height.

The easiest way to get away with this is to wrap SingleChildScrollVIew with Expanded widget

```
Column(
    children: [
        ...,
        Expanded(
             child: SingleChildScrollView(
                   child: Column()   // 2nd column
             )
        )
    ]
)
```

This will make SingleChildScrollView to take the remaining height in Column. But if you want it to be the height of specific value, then replace Expanded with a Sizedbox of specified height.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, this is the behavior I was searching for that lead me here, although I was not using Listview.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the structure by removing extra widgets like `Column`.

Wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded` to get available space for scrollabe child.

While `SingleChildScrollView` already handling scroll
event `ListView.builder` scroll event will overlap and cause issue. You can use `shrinkWrap: true, primary: false,` or `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),shrinkWrap: true,` to solve this issue.

**Demo Snippet**

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            // From here I want the Widget to be Scollable based on the List declared before
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 53,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      primary: false,
                      // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
                        "    textEval[index] $index",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          height: 2,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // The Elements between these two comments I want to be in a scrollable child view
            const Text(
              "textEval[textEval.length - 2]",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                height: 2,
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              "mainText",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                height: 2,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap ListView.builder with SizedBox and set height and width

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Column with the SingleChildScrollView().

Comment: I tried that but that's keep giving me a error of hassize indicating me that Column is causing a Error

Comment: Remove the SingleChildScrollView on the ListView.builder()
Inside the ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap : true,
physics : ScrollPhyics(),